# Cannot declare the "java-library" Gradle plugin via "alias" from "libs.versions.toml"

Tags: gradle, toml

## Is `alias(libs.plugins.java.library)` possible?

I have a bizarre desire to declare my Gradle modules' plugin dependencies via `alias`-ing them all from the `lib.versions.toml` catalog for the sake of consistency. Currently the `java-library` core Gradle plugin is declared as `id("java-library")`, but I would like it to be `alias(libs.plugins.java.library)`. However...

### When I omit the version or put "":

```ini
[plugins]
# java-library = { id = "java-library" }
java-library = { id = "java-library", version = "" }
```

I get the error `plugin version '' is invalid: cannot be null or empty`.

### When I put "1", or "_", or anything non-blank:

```ini
[plugins]
# java-library = { id = "java-library", version = "1" }
java-library = { id = "java-library", version = "_" }
```

I get the error `Plugin 'java-library' is a core Gradle plugin, which cannot be specified with a version number. Such plugins are versioned as part of Gradle. Please remove the version number from the declaration.`

Is there any way to `alias` this plugin? If not, what is the next best workaround to abstract away the magic string ID?

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17968
This is what I found when I looked into it a few months ago... I think something is in the works, but it requires some level of working around currently.  I think I struggled with the suggested syntax here, though, at least with a Groovy file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I could get until now (with Gradle 8.4) was something like this:

`libs.versions.toml`

```
[plugins]
java-library = { id = "java-library" }
```

`build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id(libs.plugins.java.library.get().pluginId)
}
```

Comment: Looks as good as it currently gets, thanks. I will update my question a bit and tick your answer.